# how hello world works faster without threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make performance test on multythread function and result showed that single threaded function works faster how it can be possible here is my code.

```
  package jollyDay;

public class JollyDay implements Runnable
{   
     public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            int i=0;
            while(true)
            //  {new JollyDay().run();i++;System.out.println(i);}
            {(new Thread(new JollyDay())).start();i++;System.out.println(i);}
        }

}
```

In threaded function i is equals to 150000 but in the function without thread i is equals to 400000 in 10 sec so why threaded is slower, shouldnt it be faster?

not: my cpu has 8 threads

Comment: Spawning new threads has a performance overhead - using them for such a small task will mean the majority of the work is done in the overhead, not in the actual code. Also, by generating an unbounded number of threads, you'll be making it hard for the OS to schedule threads (more overhead). You also won't experience much context-switching when using just one thread, but with many you might experience more.

Comment: Threading one task like that doesn't make sense. Also threading isn't "faster" it's a way to manage the CPU's execution. Computers are kind of dumb they can only do one thing at a time. So threading helps us execute our tasks in a desired order. This requires that your threads have a priority(ie. what should I do first). If you added a priority to your thread you could see your expected behavior. Also your CPU does not have 8 threads, it has 8 cores.

Comment: System.out.println() is costly too. High performance printing should use different method

Comment: It costs time to create a thread. It costs time for the CPU to manage switching between threads.

Comment: @DoesData.  Threading does not "help us execute our tasks in a desired order."  In fact, it does the exact opposite:  It _allows_ us to write tasks that execute independently of one another when we do not care about the order.  We do that for two reasons:  (A) It makes the code of some kinds of program easier to read, and (B) It allows us to speed up some kinds of computation by using multiple CPUs when they are available.  If you want to execute a sequence of tasks in a particular order, there's a really easy and obvious way to do that:  Just use one thread.

Comment: @Cihad, in addition to what everybody else said above, `System.out.println()` is a `synchronized` method.  That's where your program is spending most of its time, and only one thread can enter it at a time.  At any given moment in time, one of your thousands of threads will be in that method, and the others will all be doing nothing, waiting for their turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `Thread` is a costly operation.

In your example, you create huge amount of threads, one for each loop iteration. Therefore you spend significant amount of time just creating the threads instead of doing the actual work.

Multi threading may be faster if you take a large enough task and break it into smaller tasks that can be executed simultaneously, and execute them with a reasonable amount of threads (say, in corespondence with the number of CPUs/cores you have or a small multiply of it).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new thread at each loop, the number of threads exceed the number of your CPU cores. Since the CPU tries to be fair to each instance having say 150000 threads means that each thread only executes for sometime before being switched to the background for new thread.

Try instead creating 2 threads or 8 threads which would yield much better results.

Comment: Your suggestion to "try creating 2 threads or 8 threads" sounds simple on the surface, but really you are asking the OP change the architecture of the program to use a _thread pool_ instead of creating a new thread for each task.  That's a big step for a newbie to take, and it deserves some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Request you to go to this source here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java

It is how a Thread class is implemented in OpenJDK 6. There is a lot of work that your program is doing in every loop without producing any visible result and actually sitting idle after that. One has to be careful while trying to parallelize a piece of code because the creation of Thread instances and the scheduler efforts are also to be considered. Also, there's something called Amadahl's law. If the cost of parallelization is more than the cost saving using it, you should not do it.

If you are further interested in performance enhancement using multithreading, I'd suggest a quick read of this article here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/amdahls-law.html